# Debian host panics when running VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, debian-wheezy

We are having a strange issue with vboxdrv module in my workplace.

Most of the host machines are Debian Wheezy, and we run some Windows virtual machines, built in VirtualBox, to access Windows-only programs.

However, these machines are now crashing with kernel panic errors. The kernel is tainted due to vboxdrv module. I managed to solve this issue by updating VirtualBox to last version, but one of those still panics when running Java with the module loaded. I couldn't find anything on the web about this weird problem.

Has anyone already faced this issue? Any hint to how can I solve?

UPDATE: I just realized it always crashes showing a kernel taint flag which may not show up when cat'ing `/proc/sys/kernel/tainted`. Also, sometimes it seems to lack refreshing of kernel loaded modules, even after reboot, needing a second reboot to work properly.

Comment: The kernel taint flag may only mean that your kernel has a device driver that is not open source (what are the taint flags?). You could try `dmesg | grep -i taint` to find out which driver and post the results. Does the problem VM have different driver(s) from the others?

Comment: The taint flag is always G. I found weird the fact that in kernel panic log the taint flag is shown, but is not shown via /proc/sys/kernel/tainted. About the VM, all virtualbox versions seem to cause the problem in this specific machine.

Comment: G=GPL violation, so is not important. Please search taint in dmesg. Also, I meant device driver installed in Debian, not VirtualBox.

Comment: Nothing different from the other machines I have up and running. Please note that Debian is the host, not the guest OS.

Comment: Are the hosts the same manufacturer and hardware? (or does the odd one have a different CPU, etc)

Comment: @GregHNZ I have another machine with the same configuration which doesn't panic at all, and a second one, which has the same processor/HD but the RAM was changed from 4G to 8G, which also doesn't panic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many causes for such problems.
Here is what I found from a scan on bug-reports on the VirtualBox forums.

Some causes for such problems :

- 64 bits guests on 32 bits host
- host memory or other resource exhausted
- vitualization disabled in host bios
- A real hardware issue or kernel corruption on the host

Some possible fixes for such problems :

- disable 3D acceleration
- disable host I/O caching for the storage controller

Comment: I'm gonna scan this machine for hardware problems. Thanks!